# ILookup store item under multiple keys

Tags: .net, linq, indexing, lookup, ilookup

I have a situation where I have a set of objects, these objects relate to items in a database. We create a local cache of these objects along with indexes to allow fast filtering/searching of the data. The issue I am having is converting the list of the objects to a lookup.

the (very) simplified object:

```
String ItemID;
List<String> LocationIDs;
```

An item can belong to multiple locations and each location can contain multiple items.

I am wanting to create a lookup using the LocationIDs as keys so that I get a list of items belonging to a specific location using its location id, and any item can be found under any number of locations (keys of the lookup).

I tried the following

```
items.ToLookup(item => item.LocationIDs);
```

But this doesn't return the desired result.

The ideal usage would be:

Lookup:

```
{
    ["Location 1"] => {
        {Item 1},
        {Item 2},
        {Item 3},
        {Item 9},
    },
    ["Location 2"] => {
        {Item 2},
        {Item 4},
        {Item 3}
    },
    ["Location 3"] => {
        {Item 1},
        {Item 3},
        {Item 7}
    },
    ["Location 4"] => {
        {Item 1},
        {Item 2},
        {Item 10}
    }
}
```

Then you could easily retrieve the items for a given location.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it needs to be from LocationID -> ItemID, one way would be:

```
items.SelectMany(item => item.LocationIDs,
                 (item, locationID) => new { item.ItemID, LocationID = locationID })
     .ToLookup(tuple => tuple.LocationID, tuple => tuple.ItemID)
```

This first flattens all your data to a sequence of (itemID, locationID) tuples before turning *that* into a lookup.

It's a trivial modification to the above if the lookup needs to be from the LocationID -> Item object itself.

Comment: In your opinion what is the difference/advantage/disadvantage of using `new` to create an anonymous typed object as apposed to `Tuple.Create` in this case?

Comment: I chose the anon type for readability (esp. since this is SO and readers may have varying skill levels around these concepts). It's a little more verbose, but easier to follow than Item1, Item2 etc. If it's clear in context, there's nothing wrong with Tuple.Create IMO .